# How to get a Community User able to edit its own contact record inside the community?

Tags: community, permissions, sharing, permission-sets, partner-communities

I need provide Users under Community User Profile be able to edit their own Contact record, also Users with Partner Community Profile be able to edit their own contact and other Community Users contacts.

I've built a Lightning Component using the *$A.get("e.force:editRecord");* method and using *lightning:recordForm* tag but when clicking save this happen...

I've checked permission, sharing rules, profiles, I don't know what else to do.

Thanks in advance.

[image: error]

Comment: What are these API Names coming in error? custom objects or Fields on Contact object? If objects, check if you have given at least read access to the community profile. If fields, check for FLS of these fields to the community profile.

Comment: Those are from managed package, I have set the sharing setting public read/write to contact and accounts and nothing.